# Suspicously timed EC2 instance restart

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Yes, I've heard all the stories about EC2 instances being unreliable and how you need to proactively prepare for that.   I've also heard stories from others about how they have never had a problem, and their instances just run and run.

Today I had a strange thing happen.  I've had an Linux instance running for a couple of months, as I've been preparing to launch an e-commerce site.  I've been periodically taking snapshots.  I have my images on S3.  I have my code in a private github repo.   All things considered, I've been doing a fairly good job of protecting myself against failure.  Ironically, it was while I was doing even more in this regard today that I experienced something really strange.

Since I have these snapshots, I had assumed that the best thing to do if I needed to quickly spin up a new instance (whether due to a failed instance that wouldn't come back up, or if I just needed additional capacity) would be to take a snapshot and make a volume out of it, then make an image out of that volume, and then launch a new instance using that image.

For whatever reason, every time I've tried that lately, the new instance had a kernel panic during boot, so I decided to try a different approach.   I right-clicked on my RUNNING INSTANCE, and chose "Create Image."  That seemed like a reasonable shortcut.   Then I went to that image and launched an instance.

At almost exactly the same time, my original instance rebooted.  I didn't even see it happen.  I only know it did from the system log.  Is this just a wild coincidence?  Or did I commit a silly mistake and accidentally screw up my instance?

Fortunately, I'm just getting this new thing off the ground, so the bit of downtime didn't kill me, and I was able to very quickly get things going again.  But either I totally do not understand the "Create Image" feature from the instance list, or I got really unlucky today.

Answer (score 5):

"Create image" takes the following actions:

1. Stop EC2 instance
2. Snapshot EBS volume
3. Start EC2 instance
4. Register EBS snapshot as an AMI

So, yes, this would look like a reboot because it is like a reboot.

Here's an article I wrote on the difference between stop/start and simple reboot: http://alestic.com/2011/09/ec2-reboot-stop-start

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It's spot on.  It makes perfect since, although it certainly seemed to me that the UI didn't warn me that my instance would be shut down when I did the snapshot.  Seems like it should have.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem sounds a lot like my problem. After some searching this page helped me: http://www.raleche.com/node/138

> "The problem turned out to be the kernel. Both when creating the AMI and the instance I selected default for the kernel image.
>
> To resolve the problem, I recreated the AMI using the same kernel image as the original instance."